# aws cli cannot sync with Website-Redirect-Location metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to sync (or copy) some files from bucketA to bucketB.

In the origin bucket I have some opjects with Website-Redirect-Location metadata to redirect to other URLs.

When I perform aws sync command the object is copied but metadata disappear even if I set --metadata-directive "COPY" option command.

This is the command I'm using:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BucketA/testeo s3://BucketB/ --metadata-directive "COPY"
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is consistent with the documented behavior of the underlying API.

> If copied, the metadata, except for the version ID, remains unchanged. In addition, the server-side-encryption, storage-class, and website-redirect-location metadata from the source is not copied. If you specify this metadata explicitly in the copy request, Amazon S3 adds this metadata to the resulting object.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

Comment: Ok that makes sense why is not working.

`
"If you specify this metadata explicitly in the copy request, Amazon S3 adds this metadata to the resulting object.`

If I define the metadata value again It would work but what if I just want to copy the value of the first bucket object metadata to the second one.